# Running Code after XMLHttpRequest Finish

Tags: javascript

I have this functions

```
function C(Id)
{
    var A=Y(Id);
    alert("A"+A);    
}

function Y(idImagen)
{
    var HR= new XMLHttpRequest();       
    HR.open("Post",DownloadImg_Php,true);
    HR.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                            
    HR.onreadystatechange=function()
    {       
        if(HR.readyState==4 && HR.status==200)
        {   
            return HR.responseText;
        }
    }
    //Ejecuta el Objeto                             
    HR.send(Variables); 
}
```

So here is my problem, the alert prints undifined and im pretty sure it is because the line runs befor XMLObject finish de request which is supose tu return and asign the expected value to the variable A.

So my question is, how can stop the code from running until value from Y is returned.

Comment: you can't return from a callback. move your alert() call to the onreadystatechange() function

Comment: there is one way to achieve functionality as you desire use `Promises` here is a example https://github.com/mdn/promises-test/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use any library like `jQuery` or `Angular` with $http for making an XHR requests. It's more convenient and give us flexibility. If you don't want to, you can use `Promises`, it's on EcmaScript 6 CMIIW, you can use the `shim` from [whenjs](https://github.com/cujojs/when). It's for avoiding `callbacks spaghetti` in the future.

But if you want to use plain Javascript code, your alert must be inside

```
HR.onreadystatechange=function()
  {       
    if(HR.readyState==4 && HR.status==200)
    {
      alert("A"+HR.responseText);
    }
  }
```

Because it's `asynchronous`.